# Deep Belief Network Library

Tags: open-source, library, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a library for experimenting with [Deep Belief Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_belief_network), [a form of](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Deep_belief_networks) Neural Network.

- Must be Open Source. (I need to be able to check what it is doing, and potentially customise it.)
- Preferably would **not** support GPU. (As this makes the source code complex and hard to read/edit)
- In order of preference should be in/for C, C++, Fortran, Matlab, Python

Comment: This may seem really general, but there are very very few Deep Belief Network Libraries

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Deep Belief Networks, but it looks like the word has evolved a little since this question was asked, and I found three alternatives are more or less relevant answers:

- In Matlab: See [DeepLearnToolbox](//github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox)
- In Java: See [Deeplearning4j](//deeplearning4j.org/) or [H20 Deep Learning](//0xdata.com/product/deep-learning/)

See [Looking for a convenient way to call Java from C++](//stackoverflow.com/q/7537822/1548472) for bridging the gap from C++ to Java.

Comment: Have you used these?
DeepLearnToolBox is practically unmaintained. I've used it a lot and have a had a pullrequest there waiting for comment for over 3 months.

It works, I guess. Does technically meet the requirements.

Comment: Nope, but as no answers had been given I thought to throw some out there, to give you some options, if you hadn't located them so far.

Comment: I also use DeepLearnToolbox and can confirm Oxinabox's comment (I also have an outstanding PR, and have several others I'd *like* to submit). In it's defence as an answer to OP, I have found the Matlab code very easy to understand and modify, which is one of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of Deep Belief Networks can be found in the [nolearn](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn) library. Also in this [list](http://www.teglor.com/b/deep-learning-libraries-language-cm569/) you can find <strike>two</strike> one more DBN implementation<strike>s</strike>: <strike>[DeepLearnToolBox](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox) (MatLab) and</strike> [deepnet](https://github.com/nitishsrivastava/deepnet) (Python). Another one also in [here](https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network). Check which libraries are recently updated and how to use (if possible) without GPUs.

Comment: DeepLearnToolBox is deprecated. Please do not use it. (I say this as someone who has worked with it, and extended its DBN implementation)

Comment: @Lyndon White : Thank you, I edited my answer appropriately.